# How to dynamically change the key of the objects and merge multiple array like objects into single array using java script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, underscore.js

I have done the pre-processing calculation using javascript and finally have the following different arrays.

```
var medianArray = [{ Thomas: 94, Diana: 94, Claura: 93, Chandler: 91 }];
var q1Array = [ { Thomas: 93, Diana: 94, Claura: 92, Chandler: 91 } ];
var q3Array = [{ Thomas: 95, Diana: 95, Claura: 93, Chandler: 93 }];
var outArray = [{ Thomas: [], Diana: [85, 86, 87, 91], Claura: [94, 94, 94], Chandler: [75, 86] }];
var result = [];
```

now, I am trying to bring into a single array with meaningful keys and values in the below format.

```
[{"stdName": "Thomas", "q1" : 93, "q3" : 95, "median": 94, "outliers": []},
{"stdName": "Diana", "q1" : 93, "q3" : 95, "median": 94, "outliers": [85, 86, 87, 91]},
{"stdName": "Claura", "q1" : 93, "q3" : 95, "median": 93, "outliers": [94, 94, 94]},
{"stdName": "Chandler", "q1" : 93, "q3" : 95, "median": 91, "outliers": [75, 86]}]
```

I have searched tried multiple online resources and references of reduce(), map(), etc., but somehow not getting how to change the key name solutions.

```
[].concat(q1Array, q3Array, medianArray,outArray).forEach(function (items) {
    //logic try to add and not getting idea to proceed.
    if (!this[items]) {            
        result.push();
    }   

}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

I hope you kind of JavaScript people on Stack Overflow can help me out with this.

Comment: You have expressed your gratitude for the answer by @Reyno. Please accept that answer if you feel that your question is fully answered. On the other hand, if you're still hoping for a better solution, please indicate what's missing in your opinion.

Answer (score 2):

If all arrays have the same amount of names you can first extract all names with [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). Afterwards loop over all the names and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) them into their own object.

```js
var medianArray = [{ Thomas: 94, Diana: 94, Claura: 93, Chandler: 91 }];
var q1Array = [ { Thomas: 93, Diana: 94, Claura: 92, Chandler: 91 } ];
var q3Array = [{ Thomas: 95, Diana: 95, Claura: 93, Chandler: 93 }];
var outArray = [{ Thomas: [], Diana: [85, 86, 87, 91], Claura: [94, 94, 94], Chandler: [75, 86] }];

const names = Object.keys(medianArray[0]);

const result = names.reduce((acc, name) => {
  acc.push({
    stdName: name,
    q1: q1Array[0][name],
    q3: q3Array[0][name],
    median: medianArray[0][name],
    outliers: outArray[0][name],
  });
  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi Reyno. Thank you so much for your answer. Great! code is simple and clear.